# Ajax Post request formation while calling the api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am configuring Ajax Post request to hit an api.

below is curl command (its dummy):

```
curl -X POST \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: token' \
--header 'timestamp: test' \
--header 'sourceSystemId: test' \
--header 'sourceSystemUserId: test' \
--header 'sourceServerId: test' \
--header 'trackingId: test' \
-d '{"accountid": "123456789","modeofBusiness": "Audio"}' \
'https://services-services.c1.com:443/api/customer/v1/services/querySummary'
```

Need to reform this to hit using Ajax request. What would be the Ajax code for this? How to pass `--header` and `-d` tag in this? This api is returning response in JSON format.
Below is the Ajax code.

```
var accntno = document.getElementById('accntnoText').value;
var token = document.getElementById('tokenText').value;
//event.preventDefault();
var queryapi = "https://services-services.c1.com:443/api/customer/v1/services/querySummary";
$.ajax({
        url: queryapi,
        method: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { accountid: accntno, modeofBusiness: "Audio"},
        headers: { 'Authorization': token,'timestamp': 'test', 'sourceSystemId':'test','sourceSystemUserId': 'test', 'sourceServerId':'test','trackingId': 'test','Content-Type':'application/json'},
        success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
}
});
```

Comment: seeing as you tagged the question jquery - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Read some documentation....

Comment: @epascarello is right. RT(!F)M before posting here. But to make it easier you might want to consider - `headers`: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value', ...}, `data`: {...-d stuff...} to `$.ajax()`.

Comment: I have tried with the Ajax request and its not working.I am editing the question with Ajax code.

Answer (score 0):

For starters:

1. Your curl has `accountid` and your jQuery has `accountNumber`
2. Your http method is `post` and not `POST`
3. Your jQuery headers are missing `Accept` and has weird whitespace in the `Content-Type`

Comment: Thanks for your answer..I am passing accntno from front-end in accountid.Method post works and it is working for me..I have written some request using 'post'
That weired space came because of copy and paste from notepad..Sorry for that.where I need to include Accept?